# SQL checks Column names first instead of condition and gives me an Error Invalid column name. How to fix this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to test a column in a source table to check if it has any duplicate values. But here the situation is, the source table does not contain that column always. I have a code where it runs fine if the Column exists but gives me an Invalid column name error if the column doesn't exist.

I tried many codes where I check for the table name and the column name before executing the code. None of them worked. Below is such example:

```
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'SourceData'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'dataid')

Begin
select'SourceData' as TableName, a.dataid, b.dupcount from SourceData a inner join (select dataid, count(*) as dupcount from SourceData group by dataid having count(*) > 1) b on a.dataid = b.dataid
End
```

I want a code where it should run even if the column doesn't exist where it should give me No Output or `NULL` Output. If that column exists then it should check for the duplicate values in that column.

Comment: mysql or sql-server? They are quite different

Comment: It is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the statements are all checked at compile time already and when the objects don't exist that fails.

You can resolve this by using [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to execute your query. Though it would still fail if the objects aren't there, you can now first check for their existence and skip the `EXECUTE` if they aren't there. That way the compiler never "sees" the query and can never nag about the objects' non-existence.

```
IF EXISTS (...)
BEGIN
  EXECUTE ('SELECT ...'); -- your query goes in there as a string constant
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- do something else
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. It almost worked. But I am getting one more error as Incorrect syntax near 'SourceData'. This may be because we have used '(apostrophe) already once inside the Execute statement and cannot use it again. I tried using " for SourceData and even it did not work. Please help.

Comment: @Bharath: Yes you need to double each single quote like in `EXECUTE ('SELECT ''SourceData'' AS TableName, ...');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either dynamic SQL or better is to use stored procedures for that. This is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE testMissingColumn
(
    a int
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE testMissingColumn ADD b INT;

-- this will fail as even if it exists already, at runtime it wasn't there
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'testMissingColumn'
                    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'b' )
   SELECT  b    FROM    testMissingColumn; 

 -- will not fail as query is unknown  at runtime
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'testMissingColumn'
                    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'b' )
   EXEC('SELECT  b    FROM    testMissingColumn; ');

GO
-- stored procedures doesn't care about missing objects :)
CREATE PROCEDURE sfFestMissingColumn
AS
    SELECT  b    FROM    testMissingColumn; 
GO

EXEC sfFestMissingColumn
```